# Retrieve the value<List> from the Map and store the each value in the String variable

Tags: java

I am not able to convert the value which is the `List<String>`, of the `Map` into the `String`.

Source code is as follows:

```
Map<String ,List<String>> profileFields)

String argValue[] = null;
    int loopCounter = 0;


    Object[] obj = profileFields.values().toArray();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("Values####"+obj[i]);
        argValue[loopCounter] = (String) obj[i];
     }
```

This code is not working.

Please let me know, how I am able to convert these values to String.

Comment: Please tell us exactly what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the instantiation of the argValue-array.

```
Map<String ,List<String>> profileFields)
String argValue[] = null;
int loopCounter = 0;

Object[] obj = profileFields.values().toArray();

argValue = new String[obj.length];

for(int i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++){
    System.out.println("Values####"+obj[i]);
    argValue[loopCounter] = (String) obj[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is an array of `List<String>`.

```
Object[] obj = profileFields.values().toArray();
```

is actually

```
List<String>[] obj = profileFields.values().toArray();
```

because `values` is returning a collection of `List` objects.

**Also** Consider using Guava's [ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) which implements a `Map` of `Lists`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialze argValue:

```
String argValue[] = new String[ profileFields.values().size() ];
```

and

`loopCounter`isn't incremented either resue i or loopCounter++

This would work:

```
ArrayList<String> allLists = new ArrayList<String>();
for ( List<String> list : profileFields.values() ) {
    allLists.addAll( list );
}
String[] argValue = new String[ allLists.size() ];

for ( int i = 0 ; i < argValue.length ; i++ ) {
    argValue[i] = allLists.get( i );
    System.out.println( "Values####" + argValue[i] );
}
```

EDIT:

You also replace the last loop (without printing) by

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<String>> profileFields = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        profileFields.put("s1", new ArrayList<String>() {
            {
                add("l11");
                add("l12");
            }
        });
        profileFields.put("s2", new ArrayList<String>() {
            {
                add("l21");
                add("l22");
            }
        });

        List<String> argValue[] = null;
        int loopCounter = 0;

        //this will get you an array of elements, each element representing a Map value
        //your map Values are if type List<String>, so you'll get an array of Lists
        Object[] obj = profileFields.values().toArray();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++){
            System.out.println("Values####"+obj[i]);
            argValue[loopCounter] = (List<String>) obj[i];
         }
```